# how to change csrf field id from YII_CSRF_TOKEN to any other

Tags: php, yii, csrf

i am using Get method for form post but i am not interested if person could see if i am using yii framework. So instead of using YII_CSRF_TOKEN i need to make my own defined id name e.g. like only TOKEN.

I don't want to reveal what framework i am using , any kind of tip or help ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your application config add the below code

```
'request'=>array(    
    'csrfTokenName'=>'YOUR_TOKEN_NAME_HERE',
),
```

Comment: Thanks a lots , its so easy and cool i love yii framework...the more i am learning the more love i feel for this framework.