# how can prevent identifying Web Servers, Operating Systems and yii framwork in wappalyzer (ServerSignature)

Tags: php, security, yii2, apache-config, builtwith

i Have a yii2 project in Ubuntu server, for prevent identifying Web Servers, Operating Systems and  yii framework by wappalyzer I do some works, but I did not succeed.

1- expose_php = Off  in php.ini.

2- add ServerSignature Off and ServerTokens Prod in  apache2/apache2.conf and restart server.

3-add ServerSignature Off in .htaccess

4-change method powered() in /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/baseYii.php and return "--" instead name framework.
but in addons wappalyzer or site builtwith I see all information about my site!!

What else should I do?

Comment: I followed this: https://webhostinggeeks.com/howto/how-to-hide-apache-information-on-ubuntu-vpsdedicated-web-server/. And it works.

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov I do Instructions top, and after run curl -i http://*.*.*.*   , and get true result (Server: Apache) , but when lookup my site in builtwith.com or addons wappalyzer get all information server .

Comment: For hidding the Yii framework take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58355165/how-to-hide-yii-web-framework-name-from-wappalyzer