# Remove PHP in wappalyzer

Tags: php, yii2

here we have the Yii2 project(PHP framework).
[image]

I don't want to show PHP in wappalyzer.

- server : ubuntu 18.04
- PHP : 7.2

in php.ini I set `expose_php = off` but only remove php version from wappalyzer.

i changed PHPSESSID and yii2 crashed.

how can I remove it ?

Comment: If the analyser detects (or guesses) that you're using Yii, then it's obviously going to assume you're using PHP. As for what it's looking at to make that guess, that would be for the makers of the tool to explain if they want to, and keep secret if they prefer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about how a particular piece of software analyses websites, which could only be answered by the authors of that software.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide Yii Web Framework name from Wappalyzer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58355165/how-to-hide-yii-web-framework-name-from-wappalyzer)

Comment: @MichalHynčica Thanks, But no its NOT!